# 'useState' is not defined no-undef in REACT

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I'm totally new to React. So this is a portfolio site. When I try to run useState occuers a error in App.jsx, called

> src\App.jsx
> Line 10:35:  'useState' is not defined  no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

**App.jsx**

```
import Topbar from "./components/topbar/Topbar";
import Home from "./components/home/Home";
import AboutMe from "./components/about me/AboutMe";
import Resume from "./components/resume/Resume";
import Contact from "./components/contact me/Contact";
import "./app.scss";

function App() {
  const [menuOpen, setMenuOpen] = useState(false)
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <Topbar menuOpen={menuOpen} setMenuOpen={setMenuOpen}/>
      <div className="sections">
        <Home />
        <AboutMe />
        <Resume />
        <Contact />

      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Topbar.jsx**

```
import "./topbar.scss"

export default function Topbar({setMenuOpen,menuOpen}) {
    return (
        <div className={"topbar " + (menuOpen && "active")}>
            <div className="wrapper">
                <div className="left">
                    <a href="#home" className="logo">Prineth.me</a>
                    <div className="itemContainer">
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <div className="right">
                    <div className="nav">
                        <a href="#home" className="navTitles">Home</a>
                        <a href="#about" className="navTitles">About Me</a>
                        <a href="#resume" className="navTitles">Resume</a>
                        <a href="#contact" className="navTitles">Contact</a>
                    </div>

                    <div className="hamburger">
                        <span className="line1"></span>
                        <span className="line2"></span>
                        <span className="line3"></span>
                    </div>
                   
                </div>
            </div>
            
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: You have to import useState from react. Put this in your APP.jsx: 
`import React, { useState } from 'react';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't imported `useState`.

```
import {useState} from 'react';
```

In general, you should also import React,

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
```

but some bundler configurations make that unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

Your error is generated by this line:

```
const [menuOpen, setMenuOpen] = useState(false)
```

You could solve it by importing `useState` hook in App.jsx in this way:

```
import { useState } from 'react';
```

Comment: @prinethfernando no problem. Have a nice coding =)

Answer (score -1):

You should import `useState` in your file `App.jsx` :

```
import {useState} from 'react';
```